# Fade out animation with colors to highlight the changes on screen with Label

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in this field.I am dynamically creating controls on screen. on Button click I am changing Label value. I want to add some Fadeout animation with colors so that to catch view of user so that to indicate that something is happened on screen. Currently I am using this to hide control with fade animation

```
myLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        var a = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = 1.0,
            To = 0.0,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
        };
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        storyboard.Children.Add(a);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(a, myLabel);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
        storyboard.Completed += delegate { myLabel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; };
        storyboard.Begin();
```

instead I have to use some yello color box as background which'll FadeOut so that to indicate something happend on screen. Any help'll be appreciating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question about `Storyboard` with no xaml method doesn't look too nice.

So here's an alternative to doing the same as your posted answer from xaml:

Firstly create the `Storyboard` in xaml Resources and assign a `Key`

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard">
  <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0"
                  Duration="0:0:2"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                  To="Yellow" />
  <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:2"
                  Duration="0:0:3"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                  To="Transparent" />
</Storyboard>
```

Next since you want to invoke this from code behind on dynamic `Label` you can do something like this in your code-behind to invoke it on this dynamically added `Label`:

```
var myStoryboard = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("MyStoryboard"); 
foreach(var animation in myStoryboard.Children)
  Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, /* WhateverDynamicLabelControl */);
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

You can get working-demo of this from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbfxebjonza34ru/WpfApplication27.rar). If you can avoid the code-behind to invoke the `Storyboard`, then do go for that but I'm not sure how your View is setup for that

**Update:**

To access the same `Storyboard` from multiple views, either

- move the `Storyboard` to a higher resource scope that can be reached by both views(such as in app.xaml)
- Put the `Storyboard` in a `ResourceDictionary` and merge this dictionary into the views you need the Storyboard in.

For either of these approaches make sure you specify `x:Shared="False"` on your `Storyboard` to prevent the read-only modification error.

so instead of

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard">
```

you will have

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MyStoryboard" x:Shared="False">
```

Comment: Again perfect Viv Thanks a lot. but in this case, Storyboard we need to write for respective class, and what if we needs to access same from all classes?

Comment: @RahulSaksule not sure what you mean by "we need to write for respective class". Are you talking abt `(Label.Foreground)`? If so you can make that a bit generic by basing it a higher parent class `Control`. So instead of `(Label.Foreground)` you'd have `(Control.Foreground)`

Comment: and if you want to access it from multiple places then you can move the `Storyboard` in xaml into a higher resource scope(like app.xaml) or into a separate ResourceDictionary and merge that dictionary into the Views you need this Storyboard in. Do remember to specify `x:Shared="False"` on the `Storyboard` when doing either of these, else you might get a read-only modification error.

Comment: No No if I have two classes say A and B and both of them have labels where we have to add animation in this case we needs to write Storyboard in A and B also, if i am not wrong

Comment: ok got it so we cannot write it directly into App.xaml instead we need to use ResourceDictionary and then add into it. Thanks

Comment: @RahulSaksule see my edit for the options I'm aware of. You can add it to App.xaml however you then loose the option of "selectivity" since it gets added to all views instead of just where you need it. My preference is thus ResourceDictionary. Try to keep App.xaml not bloated

Comment: if you want to fade back to the original foreground color, use `To="{Binding Path=Color, Source = {StaticResource ActiveForegroundBrush}}"` in the XAML markup

Answer (score 1):

I have used below logic for FadeIn/FadeOut, I know this is not a best answer but it works absolutely fine for me as per my requirement.
I have used ColorAnimation as

```
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
animation.To = Colors.Yellow;
animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
animation.Completed += delegate { resetAnimation(element); };
brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
element.Background = brush;
```

and inside Completed I have reset the background from yello to transparent color

```
ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
animation.From = Colors.Yellow;
animation.To = Colors.Transparent;
animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
element.Background = brush;
```

Used both of these logic inside any method and pass element as argument. Thats it

Comment: so why has what I posted stopped working? Am assuming that's why you unaccepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change DoubleAnimation to ColorAnimation:

```
ColorAnimation colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
colorAnimation.To = Colors.Yellow;
colorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

And change this line:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(a, myLabel);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
```

to:

```
SolidColorBrush myAnimatedBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
myLabel.Background = myAnimatedBrush;
myAnimatedBrush.Color = Colors.Green;
Storyboard.SetTarget(a, myAnimatedBrush);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
```

Comment: :Yes conceptually its write to use ColorAnimation, but how to apply it? by the way code mentioned above is not working, dont know why, will you please guide me? Thanks